# Syntax confusion in Fable with EventTarget

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

I'm new to Fable/Elmish/React, and I'm trying to understand the syntax to cast an EventTarget so I can get to the `.value`

The examples I can find all use the

```
input [ Value model.Value
          OnChange (fun ev -> ev.target?value |> string
         ]
```

However I get

`None of the types 'EventTarget, string' support the operator '?'`

Instead I have to use the following syntax

```
input [ Value model.Value
          OnChange (fun ev -> (ev.target:?> HTMLInputElement ).value
         ]
```

So what gives? Am I referencing different assemblies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to

```
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
```

to see the operator `?`